# Duplicate video finder?

Tags: video, duplicate, deduplication

Is there such a thing as a duplicate video finder that will look for duplicates based on video/audio comparisons of files rather than just the file size?

Comment: If you're looking for a exact match you could try using a hash tool (MD5, SHA1) an look for matching hashes

Comment: You're talking about some hardcore file analysis here. It isn't quite as simple as taking a diff of two text files. Here is some further insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596035/programatically-comparing-two-mp4-mpeg-4-videos  or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090453/how-do-you-test-if-2-large-videos-are-identical - I don't know of any tool offhand that does this with any real degree of accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

To find duplicated Videos you can use a tool like Visual Search Pony.

> Visual Search Pony is a duplicate file removal application for
>   detecting and deleting duplicate videos according to **space, duration,
>   size, last modification time and resolution**.

Its analyzes a video to determine its attributes(resolution, duration etc.)

Its also free. Give it a try.

[Additional informations.](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/visual-search-pony-detect-and-delete-duplicate-videos-by-resolution/)(The Download on this site is broken.) [Download it from here.](http://visual-search-pony.de.malavida.com/d9346-kostenloser-download-windows)